# How can I reference a 'parent' table in a series of JOINs on SELECTs

Tags: sql, sql-server

The existing code I'm trying to modify goes something like:

```
SELECT * FROM <table1>
JOIN
( SELECT * FROM <table2>
    WHERE GETDATE() BETWEEN <fields from table2> )
```

I need to change the GETDATE() to reference a field from table1

I'd prefer to make the changes as small and local as possible as to not cause issues elsewhere so I'm hoping there's some simple way I can reference the current values from the initial SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the table an alias and you can refer to it in sub queries using that subquery.

Though you should be able to just use joins:

```
SELECT * FROM <table1> 
INNER JOIN <table2>
    ON <table1>.DateField BETWEEN <fields from table2>
```

Comment: Ah, good idea. The current implementation is using a sub-select on a single table, but I should be able to just join on that table.

Comment: Hmmm, actually this is not working. Initially the `( SELECT * FROM <table2>)` had a WHERE clause that was restricting the results for the JOIN. I tried moving that to the end, but it's not working. I think this is since there's a lot more JOINs involved that I didn't show and rather than posting all the SQL I think I should try to learn it better myself first.

Answer (score 1):

You can "name" a table to reference elsewhere in the statement:

```
SELECT * FROM <table1> AS t1
JOIN
( SELECT * FROM <table2>
    WHERE t1.field BETWEEN <fields from table2> )
```